# Why are my intents not delivered correctly?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

I'm having problems starting a service in a android app. The following code should work well. But often, not always, the Intent of the `startService` command is not correctly delivered to the `onStartCommand` method. This means that the intent is received by the service class but the extras are lost:

```
D/TestService: onStartCommand() called with: intent = [Intent { cmp=***/.services.hostConnection.TestService launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) }], flags = [0], startId = [6]
D/TestService: onStartCommand: Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=0]
```

Also I'm getting sometimes a `RuntimeException: Unable to create service ***.services.hostConnection.TestService` (full stack trace below)

I'm seaching for days now but can't find this bug...

A minimalist service class which reproduces the problem:

```
public class TestService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "TestService";
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand() called with: intent = [" + intent + "], flags = [" + flags + "], startId = [" + startId + "]");
        if(intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```

The method which starts the service:

```
public void startLongUpdates(long hostId){
    Log.d(TAG, "startLongUpdates() called");

    Intent intent = new Intent(Application.getInstance(), TestService.class).putExtra(Constants.SERVICE_ACTION_INTENT_EXTRA, HostConnectionService.LONG_UPDATE).putExtra(Constants.CONNECTED_HOST_ID_INTENT_EXTRA, hostId);
    Log.d(TAG, "startLongUpdates: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
    Application.getInstance().startService(intent);

}
```

Stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: ***, PID: 24974
                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service ***.services.hostConnection.TestService: java.lang.SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3532)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1740)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                                                            Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1693)
                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
                                                               at android.hardware.display.IDisplayManager$Stub$Proxy.getDisplayInfo(IDisplayManager.java:718)
                                                               at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal.getDisplayInfo(DisplayManagerGlobal.java:143)
                                                               at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal.getCompatibleDisplay(DisplayManagerGlobal.java:200)
                                                               at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal.getRealDisplay(DisplayManagerGlobal.java:214)
                                                               at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2183)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3499)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1740) 
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688) 
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Also sometimes this exception appears:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                         Process: ***, PID: 5355
                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service ***.services.hostConnection.TestService@9386a65 with Intent { cmp=***/.services.hostConnection.TestService (has extras) }: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown exception code: 2 msg ServiceActionIntentExtra
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3027)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                          Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown exception code: 2 msg ServiceActionIntentExtra
                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1634)
                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.serviceDoneExecuting(ActivityManagerNative.java:3814)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3019)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442) 
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="***">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name="***.Application"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name="***.gui.menu.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".gui.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="***.gui.menu.KnownHostInfoActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <service android:name="***.services.hostConnection.TestService" />

</application>
```

Application.java:

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application{
    private static final String TAG = "Application";
    private static Application application;
    public static Application getInstance(){
        return application;
    }
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        application = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you start the service the Intent variable created there is named `intent` but you're starting the service with`startService(intentTe)`. is it just a typo in the question?

Comment: Oh, you're right. That's a typo in the question.

Comment: could you please also post your AndrdoiManifest.xml?

Comment: is `void startLongUpdates(long)` an `Activity` method? and, can you share your `Application` class?

Comment: No, `startLongUpdates(long)` is in a separate class but is called by an `Activity` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem! It had to do with parcels used at the other end of the app... Actually parcels used in a loop were recycled to early and reused by other parts of the application. And so this led to various problems in many parts of the application.

Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the intent in Service onStartComamnd method. But you are wrongly getting the data from the intent. Please use below line inside the onStartCommand method,

```
String value = intent.getStringExtra(your key); // if you are sending string
```

And, I unable to understand, why are you appending **intent** object with string.

```
Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand() called with: intent = [" + intent + "], flags = [" + flags + "], startId = [" + startId + "]");
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! I'm using the `get**Extra(key)` methods to get the extra data. But in the `TestService` class I just wanted to get a minimal `Service` class. And with `intent.getExtra().toString()` I'm getting something like `Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=0]` if the extra data got lost someway. If it's still available `dataSize` is greater then 0... So my code should be correct at that point.